# Where I can find stable Office.js TypeScript definition?

Tags: typescript, office365, office-js

Where I can find stable TypeScript definition for office.js? 
I am developing an O365 app as MailApp, In my project I am using typescript throughout.

I fond https://www.napacloudapp.com/External/O365/Office.Common.d.ts
But didn't found any documentation & road-map to further updates.

Comment: [First site](https://officejstypescript.codeplex.com/) on google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the Office Extensibility team at Microsoft just released the Office.js d.ts TypeScript definitions as well, including the [newly added APIs for Excel & Word 2016](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs). You can find it on the [DefinitelyTyped github repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/office-js/index.d.ts) or on `@types/office-js`.

~ Michael Zlatkovsky

Developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: Will there be an updated version of the d.ts definition? The one linked doesn't have Office.item.saveAsync or Office.item.close functions for ItemCompose...

Comment: @alekkowalczyk I will pass this on to the Outlook team

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft I have tried the add the `@microsotf/office-js` package only (it looks like it has the typings included already so I thought that I don't need typings separated) but it doesn't work. It says that module `@microsotf/office-js cannot be found` (_if I try to import it to the main.ts_) or that `Office is not defined` (_in case of absence both `@microsotf/office-js` package and CDN csript including_) . So I had to add typings and reference the JS file from CDN. So my questions is - how to use the `@microsotf/office-js` package itself? Could you please advise me on this?

Comment: @Sergey, we have recently updated the README for office-js.  Does this help?  https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js#intellisense-definitions

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft yes thank you. I'm a pretty new to Angular so for some reason sample dotnetcore 2.1 Angular boilerplate project has `types: []` in the `tsconfig.app.json` which means - no typings load. I have spent about day on resolving

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great (and recent) example for using Typescript to build your O365 app.  https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Apps/tree/master/PeopleGraph

As per the definition, you might look here at the definition on the CodePlex site: https://officejstypescript.codeplex.com/